# Calcular la suma de los elementos debajo de la diagonal principal de una matriz en python

Tags: python, matrices

Basicamente tengo que hacer un programa que tiene que crear una matriz de NxN y llenarla de numeros random y calcular la suma de todos los elementos debajo de la diagonal principal de la matriz. Ya realize todo excepto la suma de elementos y esto es lo que tengo

```
import random

def llenar_matriz(n):
    # Llena la matriz con numeros random
    for r in range(n):
        fila = []
        for c in range(n):
            fila.append(random.randint(1,99))
        matriz.append(fila)
    return matriz

def imprimir_matriz(matriz):
    # Autodetectamos el tamaño de la matriz y la imprimimos correctamente
    filas = len(matriz)
    columnas = len(matriz[0])
    for f in range(filas):
        for c in range(columnas):
            print ("%3d" %matriz[f][c], end="")
        print()

def suma_matriz(matriz):
    suma = 0
    for x in range(matriz):
        suma = suma + matriz[x-1][x]
    return suma

# Programa principal
lado = int(input("Ingrese el ancho de la matriz: "))
matriz = []
llenar_matriz(lado)
imprimir_matriz(matriz)
total = suma_matriz(matriz)
print("La suma de los numeros debajo de la diagonal principal de la matriz es: ",total)
```

el problema es que a la hora de ejecutar esto recivo este error: "TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer".
Ademas no estoy muy seguro de si la funcion para sumar los datos debajo de la diagonal de la matriz funcionaria correctamente.

Comment: Es importante que pongas el error completo para tener el contexto. En tu caso, el error se produce en la función `suma_matriz()`, cuando en el bucle usas el `range(matriz)`. La función `range()` requiere un entero y le estás pasando una lista.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La suma de la matriz:

```
def suma_matriz(matriz):
    suma = 0
    for x in range(len(matriz[0])):
        for y in range(x):
            print(f"{x},{y}")   # Mostrar la celda que se sumara.
            suma = suma + matriz[x][y]
    return suma
```

El ancho de la matriz está dado por el `len` de su primera fila (`matriz[0]`), y el índice `x` recorre las filas desde la primera a la última.

En el segundo `for`, el índice `y` recorre desde la primera columna hasta la columna previa a la diagonal.

En cada iteración se suma la celda `matriz[x][y]`.

#### Demo

```
Ingrese el ancho de la matriz: 4
 57 94 23 23
 73 39 35 60
  3 15 26 76
  5 84 79 99
1,0
2,0
2,1
3,0
3,1
3,2
La suma de los numeros debajo de la diagonal principal de la matriz es:  259

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Te hago una pregunta. Podrias explicarme un poco mas el segundo for porfavor? ya que no entiendo como hace para recorrer hasta la columna previa a la diagonal, ya que si x recorre todas e y recorre x no se supone que recorren lo mismo?

Comment: @Gibbon. Si `x` es 3, por ejemplo, está marcando la celda [3,3], que pertenece a la diagonal. La variable `y` recorre desde cero hasta `x - 1`. En este caso, `y=0,1,2`, con lo cual tienes la coordenas (3,0), (3,1) y (3,2), todas bajo la diagonal.

Comment: Ahí lo entendí, muchas gracias por tu explicación.

Answer (score 0):

```
def suma_matriz(matriz):
    suma = 0
    for x in range(len(matriz)):
        suma = suma + matriz[x-1][x]
```

...

```
# Programa principal
lado = int(input("Ingrese el ancho de la matriz: "))
matriz = []
matriz=llenar_matriz(lado)
```

Ya hace la suma, pero tú implementación de la suma no respeta la diagonal. ¡Suerte!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).